# Using built in UITabBarItem images on Storyboard

Tags: ios

My tab bar was created through the storyboard. I am trying to figure out how to change items to use the built in images. Can the built in images only be accessed programmatically? If so, what code would I use to access them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the [UITabBarSystemItem selection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITabBarSystemItem)? You can set this in IB/Storyboard by clicking the tab bar item and then the Attributes Inspector, followed by selecting an Identifier. See the attached screenshots:

[image: Step 1]

---

[image: Step2]

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was easy but I didn't see it.

Comment: No problem. "Identifier" isn't very descriptive!